# How get the ressource size in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

How to get the size of the ressource in angularJS ?
i try this but it dosnt work

```
  $scope.respNotReadMsg = geoProvider.message.get();
  if ($scope.respNotReadMsg.length>0){

    }else{

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an async call, use the callback Luke!

```
geoProvider.message.get(function(data) {
    $scope.respNotReadMsg = data;

    if (data.length) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: it dont work, when the object dont existe it write "undifined"